# Feature Request: Both `#Header#` and `# Header #` render as headers

Tags: feature-request

Some people using the Cross Validated Stack Exchange website for the first time have difficulty formatting their sections headers.

> #### This is an Example of a Well-Formatted Section Header

In particular, there are people who have trouble with the idea that one single tiny space character `⎵` before for after a `#` could make the section header not render correctly.

```
#Approach Using a $χ^{2}$ Distribution# 
# Approach Using a $χ^{2}$ Distribution #
```

> ###Approach Using a $χ^{2}$ Distribution###
>
> #### Approach Using a $χ^{2}$ Distribution

The feature request is that headers render correctly regardless of the number of white-spaces characters to the left or right of the pound signs.

The following is a somewhat reasonable regular expression for section headers.

Feel free to amend my suggestion if you think that you can improve upon it.

> ## Level One Header `(?:^\s*)(#[^\n\r]+#?)(?:$)`
>
> ## Level Two Header `(?:^\s*)(##[^\n\r]+#?)(?:$)`
>
> ## Level Three Header `(?:^\s*)(###[^\n\r]+#?)(?:$)`

---

> - `(?:^\s*)`
>
>   - `(` ....... begin group
>   - `?:` ....... annotate group as a non-capturing group
>   - `^` ....... start of string
>   - `\s*` ....... zero or more white space carriage return, tab, new line, and more
>
>     - `\s` ....... any one white space character such as carriage return, tab, new line, and more
>     - `*` ....... zero or more
> - `(#[^\n\r]+#?)`
>
>   - `(` begin group
>   - `#` this is a number sign or pound signs or hashtags
>   - `[^\n\r]+`  one or more of anything other than newline and carriage return
>
>     - `[` begin character class
>     - `^` negate character class (invert the class)
>     - `\n\r` ...... newline and carriage return
>     - `]` .... end character class
>     - `+`  one or more
>   - `#?` zero or one number sign or pound signs or hashtags
>
>     - `#` number sign or pound signs or hashtags
>     - `?` zero or one
>   - `)` .... end group
> - `(?:$)` non-capturing group for end of string
>
>   - `?:` non-capturing
>   - `$` end of string

Comment: This must be a network-wide issue, so question should be asked at the main meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/